# Third level of sub navigation php

Tags: php, navigation

I have the following code which works perfectly for producing a two tier navigation system, the problem is I have a requirement where one section has a third level of pages below it.

Edit: The code produces a two tier side navigation item that lists the pages in this section along with the parent item detailed at the top like so:

Page Title

- Sub Page 1
- Sub Page 2

  - Another Sub Page 1

    - Further Sub Page 1
  - Another Sub Page 1
- Sub Page 3

There isn't any abnormal behaviour or error messages, it fails to display the further sub page 1 items in the list.

```
function insection_make_ul($tree, $level=0) {
$indent = str_repeat("   ", $level);
$result = "\n".$indent."<ul>\n";
foreach($tree as $id => $item) {
    $result .= $indent."<li><a href=\"".$item['permalink']."\" class=\""
        .($item['selected'] == true ? 'selected' : '')
        .($level == 0 ? ' root' : '')."\" >" . $item['title']."</a>";
    if(count(@$item['items'])) {
        $result .= insection_make_ul($item['items'], ($level+1));
        $result .= $indent."</li>\n";
    }else{
        $result .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
$result .= $indent."</ul>\n";
return $result;
```

}

```
function insection($structure_id,$custom_selected=false){
$tree = insection_array($structure_id,$custom_selected);
return insection_make_ul($tree);
```

}

and the code to build the array

```
function insection_array($data,$custom_selected=false){
global $link;
if(is_numeric($data))
    $data = fetch_row('SELECT * FROM content_structure WHERE id = '.$data);
$selected_id = $data['id'];

if($custom_selected) // dynamic item of 'real' parent
    $selected_id .= '_'.$custom_selected;

$insection = array();
if($data['parent_id'] > 0){
    if(HIDE_EMPTY_STRUCTURE){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM content_structure WHERE parent_id = '.$data['id'].' AND visible = 1 AND in_menu = 1 
                                                      AND (item_id > 0 OR redirect <> "")';
    }else{
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM content_structure WHERE parent_id = '.$data['id'].' AND visible = 1 AND in_menu = 1';
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 || $data['children_php'] != ''){
        $parent_id = $data['id'];
    }else{
        $parent_id = $data['parent_id'];
    }
}else{
    $parent_id = $data['id'];
}
while($parent_id > 0){
    $data = fetch_row('SELECT * FROM content_structure WHERE id = '.$parent_id);
    $insection[$parent_id] = array('id' => $data['id'],
        'title' => $data['menu_title'],
        'permalink' => navlink($data),
        'selected' => ($data['id'] == $selected_id ? true : false) );

    if(HIDE_EMPTY_STRUCTURE){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM content_structure WHERE parent_id = '.$parent_id.' AND visible = 1 AND in_menu = 1
                                                      AND (item_id > 0 OR redirect <> "") ORDER BY '
            .($data['sort_auto'] == 1 ? 'menu_title' : 'sort_order');
    }else{
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM content_structure WHERE parent_id = '.$parent_id.' AND visible = 1 AND in_menu = 1 ORDER BY '
            .($data['sort_auto'] == 1 ? 'menu_title' : 'sort_order');
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if(!$result){ die('error: '.mysqli_error($link)); }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $insection[$parent_id]['items'][$row['id']] = array('id' => $row['id'],
            'title' => $row['menu_title'],
            'permalink' => navlink($row),
            'selected' => ($row['id'] == $selected_id ? true : false) );
    }

    // custom start
    if($data['children_php'] != ''){ // custom sub items?
        $sub_item_result = custom_navigation_array($data['children_php']);
        foreach($sub_item_result as $sub_item){
            $id = $data['id'].'_'.$sub_item['id']; // realparent_customid
            $insection[$parent_id]['items'][$id] = array('id' => $id,
                'title' => $sub_item['menu_title'],
                'permalink' => $sub_item['href'],
                'selected' => ($id == $selected_id ? true : false) );
        }
    }
    //custom end
    $parent_id = $data['parent_id'];
}

$insection = array_reverse($insection,true);
$temp = current($insection);
$root_id = @$temp['id'];
$insection_tree[$root_id] = current($insection);

$found_selected = false;
if(is_array(@$insection_tree[$root_id]['items'])){
    foreach($insection_tree[$root_id]['items'] as $id => $item){
        if(!empty($insection[$id])){
            if($insection_tree[$root_id]['items'][$id]['selected'] == true)
                $found_selected = true;
            $insection_tree[$root_id]['items'][$id] = $insection[$id];
        }
    }
}
//if(!$found_selected){
//  while(!$found_selected){
//
//  }
//}

return $insection_tree;
```

}

Any pointers where I might get this working.

thanks

Comment: `no matter what I try it doesn't work.` Well, since its a lot of code, nobody wants to go trough your whole code. Can you please edit your question according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and tell us WHAT's not working? Tell us what you expect, and what actually happens. Error messages? Strange behaviors? Without this information I don't think that someone will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I have amended the question with some more information about what works and what part is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd advise re-looking at your code. There is a lot of code there doing the same thing. Repetition is bad. As a helping hand, here's something to get you going.

Take this menu structure as an example but It's really upto you to produce this array yourself the main thing to notice is the function which will build the array into a `<ul><li>` string.

```
        $menuItems = array(
        array(// Top level items
            "name" => "item1",
            "subs" => array(// Second Level items
                array(
                    "name" => "1a",
                    "href" => "something"
                ),
                array(
                    "name" => "1b",
                    "subs" => array(// Third Level Items
                        array("name" => "1ba", "href" => "something"),
                        array("name" => "1bb", array(
                                array("name" => "1cca", "href" => "something"),
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        array(// Top level items
            "name" => "item2",
            "subs" => array(// Second Level items
                array(
                    "name" => "2a",
                    "href" => "something"
                ),
                array(
                    "name" => "2b",
                    "subs" => array(// Third Level Items
                        array("name" => "2ba", "href" => "something"),
                        array("name" => "2bb", array(
                                array("name" => "2cca", "href" => "something"),
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
        $this->menuIterator($menuItems);
        die();
```

The following logic is the important bit, it'll mean your menu could be any levels deep you want and it'll still produce the same result:

```
public function menuIterator($items) {
    print "<ul>";
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        print "<li>";
        print "<a>{$item['name']}</a>";
        if (isset($item['subs'])) {
            $this->menuIterator($item['subs']);
        }
        print "</li>";
    }
    print "</ul>";
    return;
}
```

And the result is:

```html
<ul><li><a>item1</a><ul><li><a>1a</a></li><li><a>1b</a><ul><li><a>1ba</a></li><li><a>1bb</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a>item2</a><ul><li><a>2a</a></li><li><a>2b</a><ul><li><a>2ba</a></li><li><a>2bb</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will certainly look into refining the code when time permits, this is legacy code which isn't mine so will also look at your suggestion too.